# Portfolio Skewness and Kurtosis

Tags: probability-or-statistics, finance

I have 10 different stocks. I can easily calculate the skewness and kurtosis for each stock. But how to do it for the whole portfolio? Is there a specific function in Mathematica?

Comment: Is this useful? http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/147402

Answer (score 1):

```
Skewness[myList]

Kurtosis[myList]
```